# I want to update managed by field but am not able to do so with full name

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0

```psh
Import-Csv "D:\Scripts\computers.csv" | % {
  $Computer = $_.ComputerName
  $User = $_.UserName
  Get-ADComputer $Computer | Set-ADComputer -ManagedBy $User
}
```

If I am giving UserName = Logon Name of the User it is working fine but I want to make this work when I am giving display name in `$User`.

Comment: So what happens? No name, wrong name, partial name, error message?

Comment: I get an error like bellow : 
Set-ADComputer : Identity info provided in the extended attribute: 'ManagedBy' could not be resolved. 
Reason: 'Cannot find an object with identity: 'ABC DEF ' under: 'DC=XYZ,DC=COM'.'.

Answer (score 2):

`Set-ADComputer` needs to resolve `$User` to a Distinguished Name - which is fairly easy if you supply a unique value such as the logon name, UPN or object GUID.

If you want to use a non-unique property, such as the `DisplayName` attribute, you need to help it along by finding the user yourself:

```
Get-ADComputer $Computer | Set-ADComputer -ManagedBy $(Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$User'" | Select-Object -First 1)
```